# How to translate this sentence with three verbs to Deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german, verb, infinitive, future

> I will try to persuade your parents.

My translation is

> Ich werde mich bemühen von deinen Eltern zu überreden.

Is the grammar right?
Because there are three verbs I’m a little confused.

Comment: I wonder why you thought you had to write *von deinen Eltern* instead of *deine Eltern*. Because apart from that and the missing comma after *bemühen* it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have trouble using two verbs, it sometimes helps to add them one at a time, starting with the full verb, ending with the auxiliaries (if any). In this case, the ‘base sentence’, ‘I am persuading your parents’ is:

> Ich überrede deine Eltern.

The verb in question is *jemanden überreden* and takes an accusative object. Adding a verb for *to try* — you used *bemühen* which works, but I would prefer *versuchen* which captures the *trying* intent better — you need to put the newly-formed infinitive to the back of the sentence:

> Ich versuche, deine Eltern zu überreden.

Note that:

- the case of *deine Eltern* did not change, it remains accusative
- I put a comma before the extended infinitive because it’s more than just the verb and *zu*
- no *von* ever turned up.

Putting that into the future case — future isn’t as bad in this sentence as it would be in others, but depending on the context present tense might still be a better choice even if you’re speaking about the future — i.e., adding *werden* leaves us with:

> Ich werde versuchen, deine Eltern zu überreden.

And if you want to stick with *bemühen,* that’s fine and gives you the following results:

> Ich überrede deine Eltern.
>
> Ich bemühe mich, deine Eltern zu überreden.
>
> Ich werde mich bemühen, deine Eltern zu überreden.

Comment: I do wonder which part of this answer was unclear or not useful.